# How do I make SqlBulkCopy work with MS Enterprise Library?

Tags: enterprise-library, sqlbulkcopy

I've got some code which uses SqlBulkCopy. And now we're refactoring our code to use Enterprise Library database functions instead of standard ones. The question is how can I instantiate SqlBulkCopy? It accepts SqlConnection, and I only have DbConnection.

```
var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection)  // here connection is SqlConnection
{
    BatchSize = Settings.Default.BulkInsertBatchSize,
    NotifyAfter = 200,
    DestinationTableName = "Contacts"
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Really easy, we use it like that and it works perfectly :

```
using (DbConnection connection = db.CreateConnection())
{
    connection.Open();
    //blah blah

    //we use SqlBulkCopy that is not in the Microsoft Data Access Layer Block.
    using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy((SqlConnection) connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, null))
    {
        //init & write blah blah
    }
}
```

The solution is to cast the connection : `(SqlConnection) connection`

Comment: Oh, that's really easy. I thought about it, but haven't tried.

Have you tried using TransactionScope with SqlBulkCopy?
I've got something like:

using (new TransactionScope())
{
using (var connection = db.CreateConnection())
{
using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy((SqlConnection)connection) { /* blabla */ }
}
}

and it throws System.Transactions.TransactionManagerCommunicationException saying that MSDTC is off, although I turned it on.

Comment: Nope sorry. Never used TransactionScope.
We use the transaction parameter of the SqlBulkCopy parameter (the last parameter of the constructor, `null` in the above example)

Comment: If you just need a transaction for the BulkCopy, you can change the second parameter from `SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default` to `SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tchktcdk%28VS.80%29.aspx